# I can't get an issue token with Postman or cURL

Tags: api, curl, activecollab

I'm trying to connect to ActiveCollab API but it is impossible. I tried with Postman and cURL but I'm obtain the same result:

```
{
  "type": "ValueError",
  "message": "DOMDocument::loadXML(): Argument #1 ($source) must not be empty",
  "code": 0
}
```

This is the command with the endpoint

```
 curl -XPOST -d 'email=email@gmail.com&password=XXXXXX' https://app.activecollab.com/XXXXXX/api/v1/issue-token
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I was running into issues getting an API Token as well, albeit on a self-hosted install. I reached out to ActiveCollab support and they pointed me to a [Getting Tokens for Cloud Instances.md gist](https://gist.github.com/Elvis339/c66104950d0a7801ef544869786d2c77) which appears to have slightly different syntax with the use of a different endpoint and an "Intent" variable. Give that a look and see if it helps.

I was finally able to get an API Token with the following curl request

```bash
curl --location --request POST 'https://<URL-OF-SELF-HOSTED-VERSION>/api/v7/issue-token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "username": "<YOUR EMAIL HERE>",
    "password": "<YOUR PASSWORD HERE>",
    "client_name": "My Awesome App",
    "client_vendor": "ACME Inc"
}'
```

Based on what their support folks said, you might have luck on the cloud version with the below, ensuring to add your account ID.

```bash
curl --location --request POST 'https://app.activecollab.com/<YOUR-ACCOUNT-ID>/api/v7/issue-token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "username": "<YOUR EMAIL HERE>",
    "password": "<YOUR PASSWORD HERE>",
    "client_name": "My Awesome App",
    "client_vendor": "ACME Inc"
}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things that might help:

1. For the cloud you must use their new authentication method that requires making two requests. You can read more about it [here](https://gist.github.com/Elvis339/c66104950d0a7801ef544869786d2c77)

2. I've personally run into this exact error when making the second request to *issue-token-intent* because I was not passing in the parameters correctly. See the curl statement below to see how I got it to work:

   ```
   curl --location --request POST 'https://app.activecollab.com/YOURID/api/v1/issue-token-intent' \ 
   --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \ 
   --data-urlencode 'intent=YOURINTENTID' \ 
   --data-urlencode 'client_name=CLIENTNAME' \ 
   --data-urlencode 'client_vendor=VENDORNAME'
   ```